# MySQL cascade delete with two foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have three tables like so:

```
create table parent (  
    key1 not null  
    key2 not null  
    primary key (key1, key2)  
) engine=innodb;

create table child (  
    name  
    key1 not null  
    key2 not null  
    key3 not null  
    primary key (key1, key2, key3),  
    foreign key (key1) references parent(key1) on delete cascade,  
    foreign key (key2) references parent(key2) on delete cascade  
) engine=innodb;  

create table child_denormalization (  
    key1 not null  
    key2 not null  
    key3 not null  
    primary key (key1, key2, key3),  
    foreign key (key1) references child(key1) on delete cascade,  
    foreign key (key2) references child(key2) on delete cascade,  
    foreign key (key3) references child(key3) on delete cascade  
) engine=innodb;
```

Now, the parent table rows are uniquely identified by key1 together with key2, however multiple rows may have the same value for key1, or key2 but not both.

When I delete a row from the parent table, all rows in child with the same key1 value as the deleted row gets deleted, even though key2 is different.

Is there a way to only delete cascade if all foreign keys match the deleted row?

I tried removing "on delete cascade" and instead adding a trigger before delete on parent to manually delete the rows from child, but I still get a foreign key constraint error on child_key1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a Composite Foreign Key, instead of defining them individually:

```
create table parent (  
    key1 not null  
    key2 not null  
    primary key (key1, key2)  
) engine=innodb;

create table child (  
    name  
    key1 not null  
    key2 not null  
    key3 not null  
    primary key (key1, key2, key3),  

    -- composite foreign key instead of individual keys
    foreign key (key1, key2) references parent(key1, key2) on delete cascade 

) engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can't believe it was this simple!